# (MalformedPolicyDocument) AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli

This question has been answered here but it didn't solve my problem.

I get the `An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions` when I try to call `aws iam create-role --role-name AutoscalingRole-Name --assume-role-policy-document file://./IAM_Trust_Policy.json`

If my `IAM_Trust_Policy.json` contains only this code:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": [
                "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            ]   
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

It's working like a charm. But I needed something more, I'm creating an autoscaling role and I have a policy with these requirements:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": [
                "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
            ]   
        },
        "Action": [
            "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
            "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
            "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations",
            "autoscaling:DescribeTags",
            "autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity",
            "autoscaling:TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup",
            "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions"
        ]
    }
}
```

And for some reason I get the `An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions`

Can anyone see where I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: You are mixing >the permissions the role will have< and >who you allow to assume the role<. The first one needs be e.g. in a managed or inline policy which you attach to the role.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how should that look like? Some link or something..

Comment: In my case, it was a spelling mistake. Make sure that you mention `AssumeRole` correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @luk2302 commented, you are mixing up two policy types.  Both are required for your Role to be useful:

**Trust Policy**: *whom you allow to assume the role*

- This is your first policy document
- `Principal` is required - this is *whom you allow*
- Use this as the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` parameter in [CreateRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRole.html) .

**Access/Permissions Policies**: *the permissions the role will have*

- This is your second policy document
- `Principal` is not allowed - makes no sense here
- There are two ways to attach these permissions to your role (aka [Identity-based Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html)):

  - As a standalone Managed Policy with [AttachRolePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_AttachRolePolicy.html)
  - Or as an Inline Policy embedded in your role with [PutRolePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_PutRolePolicy.html)

In other words, remove the `Principal` from your second policy document and call `PutRolePolicy` to embed it with your role.

Comment: Thanks, I modified it and it's working. Thank you for a great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can not use role policy with assume-role-policy.
I think you are trying to rediscover the wheel.

AWS has one role for your need to autoscale `AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling` managed role.